# Calculating the number of times a motive was cited over a given period

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4. I have the following surveys table. Each row includes a motive that was cited by the respondent, represented by the `motive_value` column (think of it as motive_id).

```
---------------------------------------
id | var      | motive_value | period |
---------------------------------------
1  | 9        | 1            | 1      |
2  | 7        | 2            | 2      |
3  | 2        | 5            | 1      |
4  | 3        | 3            | 1      |
5  | 6        | 1            | 2      |
---------------------------------------
```

And motives table. There are around 20 motives, but for the sake of brevity I'm including five.

```
-----------------------------
id | value     | name       |
-----------------------------
1  | 1        | Blocked     |
2  | 2        | Delivery    |
3  | 3        | Forgotten   |
4  | 4        | Info        |
5  | 5        | Other       |
-----------------------------
```

So, I need to get, grouped by period descending, the top 5 most cited motives. ( note that, most cited motives for the entire surveys table, and not for a given period).

Here's a table that represents what I'm after.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| period | total | blocked | delivery | forgotten | info | other |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | 2     | 1       | 1        | 0         | 0    | 0     |
| 1      | 3     | 1       | 0        | 1         | 0    | 1     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `total` is the number respondents, or survey rows, in a given `period`. It's not necessary, but it's nice to have. I'd prefer not to have it if it adds lots of complexity. The other columns represent the motives, and the number of times each motive was cited. For example, in period 1 there were 3 surveys, and one of them cited the blocked motive.

I started with this query. It gets me the top 5 most cited motives.

```
SELECT
    motive_value,
    motives."name" AS motive,
    COUNT(motive_value) AS sample_size
FROM surveys
INNER JOIN motives ON surveys.motive_value = motives."value"
WHERE var BETWEEN 0 AND 10
GROUP BY motive_value, motive
ORDER BY sample_size DESC
LIMIT 5
```

I also wrote this query for one motive. It brings me, grouped by period, the number of times a motive was cited.

```
SELECT
    period,
    COUNT(motive_value) AS sample_size,
    motives."name" AS motive
FROM surveys
INNER JOIN motives ON surveys.motive_value = motives."value"
WHERE (var BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND motives_value = 1
GROUP BY period, motive
ORDER BY period DESC
```

The trouble is I need one query for each one of the top 5 motives in the first query. I also need the motives as columns, as shown in my example table. So I'm not sure how to combine those queries, or even create the table where motives are columns.

Comment: You presented your case clearly. One thing: please, always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter noted. I'm using 9.4, and I've update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figured this out using Postgresql's [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html), but with a big downside, so I'd still be interested in seeing other answers.

```
SELECT
    period,
    ("array_agg"(ROW(motive_value, motive_name, sample_size)))[1:5] AS sample_list
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            period,
            motive_value,
            COUNT(motive_value) AS sample_size,
            motives."name" AS motive_name
        FROM surveys
        INNER JOIN motives ON surveys."motive_value" = motives."value"
        WHERE var BETWEEN 0 AND 10
        GROUP BY period, motive_value, motive_name
        ORDER BY sample_size DESC
    ) AS row
GROUP BY period
ORDER BY period DESC
LIMIT 6
```

The only down side is that, instead of columns, I get an array like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| period | sample_list                                                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | {"(1,\"Blocked\",1)", "(2,\"Delivery\",1)", ... }                |
| 1      | {"(1,\"Blocked\",1)", "(3,\"Forgotten\",1)", "(5,\"Other\",1)" } |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There is no column `surveys."value"` in the question. Is that supposed to be `surveys.motive_value`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, indeed it is `motive_value`, sorry, about it that.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get a result of yet unknown column names. SQL demands to know names and data types of columns to return at least at call time.

You can either run two queries: the first to build your statement and the second to execute it.

Or you try this - if it's enough to have column names in the first row of data:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$
   WITH top5 AS (
      SELECT motive_value
           , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC, motive_value) AS rn
      FROM   surveys
      GROUP  BY 1
      ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
      LIMIT  5
      )
   SELECT NULL::int AS period  -- assuming integer, use your actual data type
        , NULL::int AS total
        , t.rn, m.name
   FROM   top5 t
   JOIN   motives m ON m."value" = t.motive_value

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT s.period
        , sum(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY period)::int AS total
        , t.rn, count(*)::text AS ct
   FROM   top5 t
   JOIN   surveys s USING (motive_value)
   GROUP  BY s.period, t.rn
   ORDER  BY period NULLS FIRST, rn
   $$
  ,'VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)'
  ) AS ct (period int, total int
         , motive1 text, motive2 text, motive3 text, motive4 text, motive5 text);
```

(Untested.)

`crosstab()` is supplied by the [additional module **`tablefunc`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html). To install (once per database):

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Detailed explanation for `crosstab()`:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

About "dynamic" crosstab:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514334/939860)